# Show/hide fields based on value of another field

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a scenario where a field should be shown as dropdown or text field based on the value of another field.

**Example:**

User to select State as dropdown (California, North Carolina, etc) if the selected country is USA.

If any other country is selected (other than USA), user should be shown only a editable text field (instead of dropdown).

Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this using backpack's out-of-the box features.  If not, is there any workaround possible?

My code snippet:

**COUNTRY FIELD FROM DB:**

```
CRUD::addField([
       // 1-n relationship
       'name'      => 'countryid', // the column that contains the ID of that connected entity;
       'label'     => 'Country', // Table column heading
       'type'      => 'select2',
       'entity'    => 'getcountryid', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
       // optional
       //'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
       'model'     => "App\Models\Country", // foreign key model
    ]);
```

**STATE FIELD WHICH DEPENDS ON COUNTRY FIELD**
(*THIS SHOULD BE MADE AS A TEXT FILED OR DROPDOWN BASED ON THE COUNTRY SELECTED*):

```
CRUD::addField([ // select2_from_ajax: 1-n relationship
'label'                => "State", // Table column heading
'type'                 => 'select2_from_ajax',
'name'                 => 'countrystateid', // the column that contains the ID of that connected entity;
'entity'               => 'countrystate', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
'attribute'            => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
'data_source'          => url('/api/countrystate'), // url to controller search function (with /{id} should return model)
'placeholder'          => 'Select an Indian state', // placeholder for the select
'minimum_input_length' => 0, // minimum characters to type before querying results
'dependencies'         => ['countryid'], // when a dependency changes, this select2 is reset to null
//'method'                    => 'GET', // optional - HTTP method to use for the AJAX call ]); (GET, POST)
]);
```

Comment: Did you try some variants? Share your code then

Comment: I tried select2_from_ajax and it works fine.  However I am not able to dynamically change (disable/enable) the control to a text field and dropdown.   I will share my code soon.

Comment: Due to lack of ideas I have made a work around in my project to isolate the country and state.